# PyCharm keyboard shortcut and highlight issues

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new to PyCharm and when I went to highlight something to cut it and paste it somewhere in my code, it put me into insert and wouldn't let me do anything with my selection.

Does anyone know how to fix putting me into insert when I highlight and how I get to my normal shortcuts, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "put me into insert"? Are you using PyCharm with vi-style key bindings? You didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Make sure you don't have IdeaVim plugin installed (Settings | Plugins).

Comment: @PavelKarateev if you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct, thanks for helping me out!